# How to pre-select AG-Grid filter dropdown checkbox values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

Is there a way to pre-select a value or values for the filter checkbox?

I am currently saving the last filter so if a user filters, leaves the page, and then comes back the grid is still filtered. The issue I'm having is the filter drop down checkboxes does not reflect the filtered rows.

[image]

Here is the code I am using to set the saved filter:

```
if ($scope.onFilterChanged) {
 this.gridOptions.onFilterModified = function () {
        $scope.onFilterChanged({filter: ctrl.gridOptions.api.getFilterModel()});
  }
 }

if ($scope.currentFilter && $scope.onFilterChanged) {
    this.gridOptions.api.setFilterModel($scope.currentFilter);
} else {
    this.gridOptions.api.setFilterModel(null);
}
```

setFilterModel works great if I'm not leaving the page and coming back. But I'm not sure why it updates the rows and not the drop down options on page load..Is there a way to get the filtered rows and the check boxes to match on page load?

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible via [filter API](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/#accessing-filter-component-instances)

You need to get filter instance first

```
let filterInstance = this.gridOptions.api.getFilterInstance('columnNameHere');
```

Then you can decide what should be in the filter

```
filterInstance.selectNothing();
filterInstance.selectValue("value one");
filterInstance.selectValue("value two");
...or...
let model = ["value one", "value two"];
filterInstance.setModel(model);
```

And on the last step - just inform the grid about changes

```
this.gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting this error: TypeError: this.gridOptions.api.getFilterInstance is not a function. Do you know what version that api method became available?

Comment: Also, why does setFilterModel set the rows on page load but not the actual drop down options accordingly as well? Any idea? It sets both fine if you don't leave the page

Comment: implement `onGridReady(params)` on your `html` `ag-grid` element and bind `this.gridApi = params.api;` inside, and use `this.gridApi` instead of `this.gridOptions.api`

Comment: onGridReady doesn't seem to do anything for me.I have <grid onGridReady(params)></grid>, does that bind into my grid component code because I need to be able to access getFilterInstance there.

Comment: provide a plnkr sample pls

Comment: Sorry given the depth of the code that would take a while to complete. I'm using "this.gridOptions.api.getFilterInstance" in the line above where I'm using "this.gridOptions.api.setFilterModel" and only getFilterInstance gives me an error. This is an older project I have version 2.3.0 of Ag-grid. I'm thinking getFilterInstance was not available then?

Comment: oh, 2.3.0 version - yep seems its too old.